# Solving Eigen System in c#?

Tags: c#, image-processing, computer-vision, eigenvalue, eigen

Do you know of a good library/way that I can use to solve an eigen system in c#?

My data is 2D/3D and I want to get direction and length of first and second eigen vectors to evaluate how my data is elongated in 2D space.

Thanks

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400203/calculating-eigenvectors-in-c-using-advanced-matrix-library-in-c-net

Comment: By the way, you probably need SVD, not eigenvector decomposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to guys who suggested Alglib but its naming convention is c++ style and I didn't find it easy to use!

Instead I found a brilliant opensource library called [Accord.Math](http://accord-net.origo.ethz.ch/). It provides a fantastic API for mathematics which very well satisfies my needs.

I first found a Normalized EigenValue decomposition code [here](http://crsouza.blogspot.com/2010/06/generalized-eigenvalue-decomposition-in.html), but apparently it is already added to Accord.Math library.

My code looks like this:

```
var gevd = new EigenvalueDecomposition(rect);
var V = gevd.Eigenvectors;
var D = gevd.DiagonalMatrix;
```

It also provides other types of decompositions:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Maybe [this library](http://www.alglib.net/eigen/nonsymmetric/nonsymmetricevd.php) can help you.

Answer (score 5):

[Alglib](http://www.alglib.net/matrixops/general/svd.php) is GPL2.