# Calculating EigenVectors in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there any way to calculate EigenVectors and eigenvalue  in C#?

I found this question [Calculating EigenVectors in C# using Advanced Matrix Library in C#. NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4400203/calculating-eigenvectors-in-c-sharp-using-advanced-matrix-library-in-c-net)

but the library has been removed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ALGLIB library can calculate them and they support C# and C++. You can view it [here](http://www.alglib.net/eigen/nonsymmetric/nonsymmetricevd.php). Its open source, and their description of the module is:

> The RMatrixEVD subroutine finds the eigenvalues and, if needed, the
>   eigenvectors (right and/or left) of a general matrix. The subroutine
>   uses matrix A as the input and returns the array of eigenvalues (real
>   and imaginary parts) and the array of eigenvectors (the array
>   structure is described in detail in the subroutine comments).